# Error when running apt-get - broken packages

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am getting this error while trying to run `apt-get install` anything in the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f 
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... 
Done Correcting dependencies... failed. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : 
   Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers (= 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2) but 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1.1 is installed
   Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad (= 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2) but it is not installed  
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers : 
   Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1.1) but 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 is installed  
jitsi:i386 : 
    Depends: default-jre:i386 but it is not installed or
                       java7-runtime:i386
              Depends: libappindicator1:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libspeex1:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: jitsi-archive-keyring:i386 but it is not installable  libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 : Depends: libopencv-highgui2.4-deb0 but it is not installed  libopencv-contrib2.4v5 : Depends: libopencv-highgui2.4-deb0 (=
2.4.9.1+dfsg1-1) but it is not installed  libopencv-features2d2.4v5 : Depends: libopencv-highgui2.4-deb0 but it is not installed
                             Depends: libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg1-1) but 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 is installed  
libopencv-flann2.4v5 : 
  Depends: libopencv-core2.4v5 (=
2.4.9.1+dfsg1-1) but 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 is installed  
libopencv-legacy2.4v5 : 
  Depends: libopencv-highgui2.4-deb0 (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg1-1) but it is not installed  
libopencv-ml2.4v5 : 
   Depends: libopencv-core2.4v5 (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg1-1) but 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 is installed  
libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 : 
  Depends: libopencv-highgui2.4-deb0 (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg1-1) but it is not installed   
libopencv-video2.4v5 : 
  Depends: libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 (=
2.4.9.1+dfsg1-1) but 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 is installed 
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. 
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following commands on your terminal

`sudo apt-get --fix-broken
 sudo apt-get --build-dep
 sudo apt-get check`

Comment: didn't worked for me, same error comes in every apt-get

Comment: sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name
this works like magic :)

Comment: @frodo Your last comment seems to be an answer that worked for you. Consider to [answer your own question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) to indicate the question has been solved.

Comment: The valid answer from the OP himself is in the comments of this answer. I propose not to delete the answer to keep the comment, until @frodo or anybody else has made it a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was a strange one. The [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901168/error-when-running-apt-get-broken-packages#comment1413660_901185) mentioned under the other answer didn't work for me.

Although the question's title suggests otherwise, I think this problem is

### specifically about the installation of [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/Main/Download), so it won't work for the general case of missing dependencies.

The missing dependency reported is `jitsi-archive-keyring`, which I found on https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/:

https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/jitsi-archive-keyring_1.0.1_all.deb

So after downloading, I installed this package first via

```
sudo dpkg -i jitsi-archive-keyring_1.0.1_all.deb
```

before installing Jitsi ([.deb file of version 2.10.5550-1 here](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/jitsi_2.10.5550-1_amd64.deb)) via

```
sudo dpkg -i jitsi_2.10.5550-1_amd64.deb
```

As mentioned in the question, use

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

whenever one of the aforementioned `dpkg` calls fail due to dependency errors and retry them again afterwards.

This solved this issue for me on Xubuntu 16.04.